# Unable to start MySQL server while configuring MySQL Cluster using its auto installer GUI?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

We are trying to configure MySQL Cluster using its Auto Installer GUI. When we click on 'Deploy and Start MySQL Cluster' button, it showing a small popup with progress. Once it is reached at 57%, after that the progress won't be changed at all.

Using Inspect Element, we identified that, the error is related to start Mysql server. Here the screenshot

[image]

Also, we want to know that, whether we need to install Mysql Server before or after configuring Mysql Cluster installation. We are trying to do this by using a Single host.

Please help us, if anyone aware about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are experiencing exactly the same problem, the installation stops at 57%. We are trying to install it on CentOS 6.5, what OS do you use?

Comment: We are on Ubuntu 12.04. We dropped this attempt since AWS marketplace provides MySQL cluster instance. Go to AWS marketplace and search with MySQL Clustrix...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by opening all firewall ports between the physical (or virtual) machines used in the cluster. 
PS. Also, make sure that you have 22 and 1186 ports opened for the machine where you have "MySQL Cluster Installer" running.